# Convert a Windows Forms app to Metro UI app

Tags: windows, winforms, microsoft-metro

Using Visual Studio 2012 Desktop I created a Windows Forms app in C#.  It runs fine on Windows 8, and from the Win8 start menu, I can click it (I had to put a shortcut in the start menu) but switches to the desktop and then opens a window like any normal desktop app would.

Is there a way to have it open like the Microsoft apps do and not switch to the desktop first? Things like IE and Skype do this - it's like a single app mode basically.  I don't really know what to call it since I'm relatively new to Win8 Metro goodness.

I have a feeling I will need to rewrite this thing in WPF.  Is this true?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's quite difficult.
Maybe we can seperate the logical code and UI code , reserve the logical code and recreate a UI for Metro Style. It's hard to convert the WinForm UI code to Metro's.
Metro apps based on WinRT have many differents from WinForm, not only the namespace or method name but some implementing code are different. There are lots of method we can use or information we can get in WinForm are not supported in Metro. 
Converting WinForm to Metro will be a large project I think.

Comment: Do you know if that means creating a Windows Store app?  The main control that I really want is the Webbrowser, and it seems like Windows Store only has WebView, which is rather crippled in comparison.